# изменение размера текста в зависимости от размера окна

Tags: unity3d

что мне покрутить в настройках чтобы текст менял размер в зависимости от размера окна (только для пк)

Answer (score 0):

В параметрах Canvas есть такая функция: `Scale with`, там нужно выбрать `Scale with screen size`